# How to modify or run this query in foxpro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have the SQL query like this

```
   select * from tablename  where Fieldname not in (10005347797,1006009285)
```

My aim is to delete remaining records not in that id.So before that I want to see all the records in that table those  are going to be deleted.
If you know how to delete that records you can give me delete command also.

Comment: You can use the SQL DELETE command as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kt4x6zx(v=vs.71).aspx or the native VFP DELETE command as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wytye2b3(v=vs.71).aspx. Examples given by others in the answers below. The SQL version performs record locking but the native command can be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question:

type of 10005347797 and 1006009285 are 'string'?

if so, try this ('alltrim' just in case):

> delete tablename for not
>   inlist(alltrim(Fieldname),'10005347797','1006009285')

else

> just use without the single quotes

endif

- btw, English is not my 1st language

Comment: Is this even valid VFP? It's certainly not valid SQL.

Comment: If you want to specify the table name / work area you need to use the IN clause as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wytye2b3(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates how to use a SQL command to delete records.

```
CREATE CURSOR Table1 (pk I)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO Table1 (pk) VALUES(5)

SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.pk NOT IN (2, 4)

DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.pk NOT IN (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

FoxPro commands to get the result for you:

```
BROWSE LAST FOR NOT INLIST(FIELDNAME, 10005347797, 1006009285) && view/edit the records
DELETE FOR NOT INLIST(FIELDNAME,10005347797, 1006009285) && mark the records for deletion
PACK && permanently delete the marked records
```

Note: Based on my experience with FoxPro, these commands should work with any version of FoxPro. However it is not tested.